# Remote login as root in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

In my project, I have to install some package remotely. If I have to login in debian, I say:

```
$ ssh root@remotehostname
root@remotehostname's password:
```

it logs in successfully.

I have login in **ubuntu** in directly using

```
 $ root@remotehostname
 root@remotehostname's password:
```

it is throw error message in

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: 1. Off-topic.  2. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I want login as a root in ubuntu ....

Comment: @devnull thanks for editing in my code...

Comment: It is a security risk to enable root login via ssh. Because, malicious programs may attempt brute force login on root@some-server. And if they succeed they can do what they want.

Comment: I have developed in deb package in my project,that package install in various OS. So i have write the installation script,that script run in remotely,So i need root login

Comment: You *want* to login as root. You don't *need* to. Login using your personal account and use `sudo` as needed.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6676/why-is-there-no-option-to-login-as-root

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) says:

> **By default, the Root account password is locked in Ubuntu.**

It also says:

> **Please keep in mind, a substantial number of Ubuntu users are new to
>   Linux.** There is a learning curve associated with any OS and many new
>   users try to take shortcuts by enabling the root account, logging in
>   as root, and changing ownership of system files.

It talks at length about why it's been done this way.

---

Enabling the root account:

```
sudo -i
```

To enable the Root account (i.e. set a password) use:

```
sudo passwd root
```

**Use at your own risk!**

> **Logging in to X as root may cause very serious trouble.** If you believe
>   you need a root account to perform a certain action, **please consult
>   the official support channels first**, to make sure there is not a
>   better alternative.

Answer (score 22):

check the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` whether the configure `PermitRootLogin yes` below `# Authentication:`  . If not `yes`, it doesn't permit login as root.

you can change it to `yes`.

Then, restart ssh service to apply the changes:
`sudo service sshd restart`

For Ubuntu 23.04
`sudo service ssh restart`

Comment: This is irrelevant as the user is able to login as root via SSH

Answer (score 11):

**Do not enable the root account. Do not set a password for the root account.**

A better way is to allow root login using public key authentication, not with password. [The reasoning is explained in the Debian mailing list archives.](http://lists.debian.org/debian-security/2002/06/msg00418.html)

1. Open `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and check if `PermitRootLogin` is set to `yes`. If not, then set it to yes and restart `ssh` with `sudo service ssh restart`
2. Create the `.ssh` directory in root's home if it doesn't exist and make sure it has strict permissions:

   ```
   sudo -i mkdir -p .ssh
   sudo -i chmod 700 .ssh
   ```
3. Create a public/private key pair in the system you want to login from.
4. Copy your public key to your regular user account.
5. Append your public key to `.ssh/authorized_keys` of root, and make sure the file has strict permissions:

   ```
   cat id_rsa.pub | sudo -i tee -a .ssh/authorized_keys
   sudo -i chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

With this setup you should be able to login as root using your private key.

If you have previously enabled the `root` account, make sure to disable it now:

```
sudo passwd -l root
```

Answer (score 4):

You could set a password for root, but this is not recommended and could open a security risk. But if you have an user account on the target system that has sudo credentials, you could log in as user:

```
ssh user@remotehostname
user@remotehostname's password:
```

and then do what you want using sudo or get a root shell the recommended way:

```
user@remotehostname$ sudo su
Password:
root@remotehostname#
```

and then do your housekeeping. Instead of 'sudo su' you also could use 'sudo -i', which is equivalent, or 'sudo -s', that keeps the current environment.

See [Ubuntu Sudo/Root documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Answer (score 3):

edit your /etc/sshd_config doing:

```
sudo /etc/sshd_config
```

search for line having **PermitRootLogin** into *Authentication* Section and uncomment **PermitRootLogin** or set **PermitRootLogin yes**. Or simply add this line to the end of file:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Next you'll gonna restart ssh daemon doing

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

or

```
service ssh restart
```

depending on your linux distribution
Now you'll login via ssh with your root account
Warning: For security reason this is not recommended. What you can do is login with any other accound via ssh and within your user session do:

```
sudo command
```

or simply:

```
sudo su
```

to continue session under your root account

Answer (score 3):

```
ssh -l user localhost "sudo whoami"
```

returns:

```
root
```

So long as:

1. The remote host allows the user connecting to be able to sudo without asking for a further password.
2. ssh-copy-id has been run or correct keys copied across to remote host so that the user can connect again without a password via ssh

All that is different was the word sudo was added before carrying out the command

If there are security issues with keys etc then you could take a look at a language called expect - using an expect script you will be able to ssh / telnet what ever it is to a remote host and send passwords etc accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I think the only time I ever tired to log in as root was the first time I used AWS EC2 and I tried to long in as root because I knew it existed. The user name ec2-user.

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit sshd_config file `vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. Comment out `#PermitRootLogin without-password` under Authentication:
3. insert below `PermitRootLogin yes`
4. Save the file.
5. Restart the ssh service `service ssh restart`

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Root account password is locked in Debian based systems like Ubuntu:

Switch to `root` account user:

```
sudo -i;
```

Now set the password for root account:

```
sudo passwd;
```

Simply adding a password for root is not enough.

Incoming ssh connections need to be enabled as below:

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and find out the following line:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

Just replace the word `without-password` with `yes`, as in the following line:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Then restart SSH:

```
sudo service ssh restart;
```

Finally Restart the system:

```
sudo reboot;
```

Done !!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit the 
   `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and change the line that says “PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only” to “PermitRootLogin without-password”.
2. Restart the sshd server with “`service sshd restart`”.
3. Edit the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. This file should have one line only. It starts by “echo” or “command … sleep 10;” then you can see “ssh-rsa [big long key]”. Remove the text from the beginning of the line until where it says “ssh-rsa”.

SSH your machine using root with your keypair